# Will timebased workflow triggers even if the not record is edited?

Tags: workflow, process-builder, time-dependent-workflow

I have a requirement where an email should be sent to the customers before 30 days of their subscription last date, Can I do it using time based workflow, there will be no manual intervention for the records. IT should automatically pick up the records and should send mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the first option "when record get created" and in that use "30 days before subscription last date". It will trigger the email.

Comment: Will it works for existing records?

Comment: @Raghu no it wont work for existing records.

Comment: Can I just make a dummy update and make the opportunities edited, will it work at that time?

Comment: @Raghu then you need to choose the third option and need to match criteria.